# How to get second pandas dataframe showing net trade based on first pandas dataframe containing one-directional trade in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` as shown below:
It shows exports volume from A to B, B to A and A to C in three rows. Trade is possible in both directions.
[image]

`df1.to_dict()` returns

> {'Country1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A'},  'Country2': {0: 'B', 1: 'A',
> 2: 'C'},  'Value': {0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 3}}

I want a second dataframe `df2` based on `df1` which shows the net trade volume between countries.
For example, A to C has a net trade volume of 3 units, and B to A has a net trade volume of 2 units (5-3). This needs to be reflected in the second dataframe as shown below:
[image]

How can I automate creating `df2` based on `df1`?
I have large number of countries, so I want to automate this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could swap the names, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and filter:

```
val = (df[['Country1', 'Country2']]
 .merge(df.rename(columns={'Country1': 'Country2',
                           'Country2': 'Country1'}),
        how='left')['Value']
 .rsub(df['Value'], fill_value=0)
)

out = (df.assign(**{'Net Value': val})
         .query('`Net Value` >= 0')
         .drop(columns='Value')
      )
```

Output:

```
  Country1 Country2  Net Value
1        B        A        2.0
2        A        C        3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, which uses [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new dataframe with row-wise sorted countries, and then summing by group of countries ([`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html)):

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    [[x, y, z] if x < y else [y, x, -z] 
     for x, y, z in zip(*[df[col] for col in df])], 
    columns=df.columns)
.groupby(['Country1', 'Country2'], as_index=False).sum())
```

Output:

```
  Country1 Country2  Value
0        A        B     -2
1        A        C      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```py
df = (
    df.sort_values(by="Value", ascending=False)
    .assign(tmp=df[["Country1", "Country2"]].agg(frozenset, axis=1))
    .groupby("tmp")
    .agg(
        {
            "Country1": "first",
            "Country2": "first",
            "Value": lambda x: x if len(x) == 1 else x[1] - x[0],
        }
    )
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Country1 Country2  Value
0        B        A      2
1        A        C      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different, simple and easy to understand approach for myself.

First, I created new columns `First country` and `Second country` based on which country among `Country1` and `Country2` come first and second in the alphabetical order.

```
df2 = df1.copy()
    df2["First country"] = df2.apply(lambda row: min(row["Country1"], row["Country2"]), axis = 1)
    df2["Second country"] = df2.apply(lambda row: max(row["Country1"], row["Country2"]), axis = 1)
```

[image]

Second, I created `Net Value` column calculating net value for each row based on `First country` and Second country columns.

```
df2["Net Value"] = df2.apply(lambda row: row["Value"] if row["First country"] == row["Country1"] else -row["Value"], axis=1)
```

[image]

Next, I used groupby function and retained only relevant columns for myself:

df2 = df2.groupby(["First country", "Second country"]).agg({"Net Value":"sum"}).reset_index()
df2 = df2[["First country", "Second country","Net Value"]]
df2

Complete code is as follows:

```
df2 = df1.copy()
df2["First country"] = df2.apply(lambda row: min(row["Country1"], row["Country2"]), axis = 1)
df2["Second country"] = df2.apply(lambda row: max(row["Country1"], row["Country2"]), axis = 1)

df2["Net Value"] = df2.apply(lambda row: row["Value"] if row["First country"] == row["Country1"] else -row["Value"], axis=1)

df2 = df2.groupby(["First country", "Second country"]).agg({"Net Value":"sum"}).reset_index()
df2 = df2[["First country", "Second country","Net Value"]]
df2
```

Final results:
[image]

The negative value is also fine for me.